# Show $f_t(x)=x(1+t(1-x))<1$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

How can I show that $f_t(x)=x(1+t(1-x))<1$ for $t\in (0,1]$ arbitrary and every $x\in (0,1)$?
Thanks for a hint, I only got $\leq$.

Comment: I suggest that show how you got $\le$, you are probably very close to the solution.

Comment: @MartinR I got $f_t(x)$ is monotone increasing on $(0,1)$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ so $f(x) \in [0,1]$ for $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is *strictly* increasing?

Comment: yes, it is strictly increasing on $[0,1)$, right?

Comment: If it's strictly increasing on $[0,1)$ and it's monotone increasing on $[0,1]$ it will be strictly increasing on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to solve it without recourse to
differentiation, which will identify when a given differentiable function is
increasing. So, here is a simpler solution: Clearly,
\begin{equation*}
f_{t}(x)=x(1+t(1-x))<1
\end{equation*}
holds if and only if
\begin{equation*}
0<1-x(1+t(1-x))=(1-x)(1-tx)\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where it is straightforward to see that $0<1-x$ and $0<1-tx$ whenever $x\in
(0,1)$ and $t\in (0,1]$.

Hope this helps.